# SQL = vs LIKE vs LIKE BINARY, not case sensitive

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have encountered rather weird behavior with SQL LIKE, = and LIKE BINARY

Note : The first 3 characters of password is actually `3Vf` and the rest of the query is syntactically correct too.

```
SUBSTRING(password,1, 3) = "3VF"      -> returns true
SUBSTRING(password,1, 3) = "3Vf"      -> returns true

SUBSTRING(password,1, 3) LIKE "3VF"   -> returns true
SUBSTRING(password,1, 3) LIKE "3Vf"   -> returns true
```

However if i use LIKE BINARY, i get case sensitive behavior

```
SUBSTRING(password,1, 3) LIKE BINARY "3VF"   -> returns false
SUBSTRING(password,1, 3) LIKE BINARY "3Vf"   -> returns true
```

I dont understand why the comparisions are case insensitive. Considering the password is a `VARCHAR(64)`. In all the resources I've seen online it says that = and LIKE both are case sensitive.

Note: the full query I'm running is

```
SELECT * from users where username="natas16" AND SUBSTRING(password,1, 3) = XX
```

Also, This is **NOT** a real world application but a natas level. It is sort of a 'hacking' playground. They have different levels with vulnerabilities you are supposed to exploit. So this is not a real world example.

http://www.overthewire.org/wargames/natas/

Comment: just so we are clear, you are not supposed to store passwords in a database.  use the `PASSWORD('Function')` to properly store it.  Though the behavior you are describing is very odd. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-hashing.html

Comment: are you saving passsword as plain text?? Do use an hash key and column  collate as latin_colate_cs.

Comment: natas is sort of a ethical hacking playground. You get a challenge and you are supposed to break in somehow. the aim of this is to brute force it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whether the `LIKE` and `=` act in a case sensitive manner will be determined by the collation of the field you are doing the comparison on.  If your field has a non-case-sensitive collation (like I'm guessing yours does) then you get non-case-sensitive comparison results.  If the field has a binary or case-sensitive collation or if you used the `BINARY` keyword on the comparison to force a binary comparison, you would get the case-sensitive comparison.

Comment: Thankyou, I guess thats the only explanation here. Since I cant directly see the database schema I'm gonna guess this is whats happening. Also, Is this a common pitfall? I mean I've always thought text comparisons are case sensitive no matter what.

Comment: @AhmedAeonAxan I guess it could be a pitfall if you don't understand how collations work, as your application could certainly get unexpected results as you are getting. Not sure how common of a problem it is.  Most don't actually put password in DB in clear text but rather hash them for storage in a medium that has all lowercase letters (like md5 hash or similar), such that case-sensitivity isn't a problem.

Comment: yes i unerstand that. I've edited my post to include this. This is all part of a natas level. It is basically a sandbox with some kind of vulnerability you are supposed to exploit. So this is far from a real world application. And because of this I cant exactly see their database schema either. But your answer fully describes the behaviour So i guess this must be it.

Answer (score -1):

Read abt the collate option and how to make it case sensitive from mysql [tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html)

Comment: This link-reliant hint might have been a comment under the question.